# My app is crashing when using Google Admob

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, admob

I'm trying to display an ad in the mainActivity, and i've copied the code from here -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/targeting#test_ads
but using my own credentials.

I know there are other ppl on here that have had the same 'null object reference' error but their solutions aren't working don't seem to be fixing it. 
The app runs when the adView.loadAd is commented out.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx");

        AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                //.addTestDevice("Device ID")        // All emulators

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        Music.playMusic(this.getApplicationContext(), 1, 0, 3, 0);

        // Display the Main Activity.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        highscore.highscoreSetorGet(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, 0, 0, 0, false);
        displayHighscore();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**string.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="admob_id">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx</string>
</resources>
```

**Error...**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.sam.myfirstapp, PID: 2362
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sam.myfirstapp/com.example.sam.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.sam.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Application terminated.

Comment: 1) Never ever `new` any Activity class. 2) You never called `setContentView` before any `findViewById`

Comment: In other words, move `setContentView` after `super.onCreate`. Try to always put it there, too

Comment: @cricket_007 Thats has fixed it. Nice one!!!